# How to find $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(a≤(X_1X_2...X_n)^{-n/2}e^{n/2}≤b)$ where $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim U[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I am trying to calculate 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(a≤(X_1X_2...X_n)^{-n/2}e^{n/2}≤b)$$
in terms of $a,b$,
where $$X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim U[0,1]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(i.i.d.)$$ and $$0≤a<b$$
My attempt is to take natural logarithm on both sides, and end up with a r.v $Y=\ln{X_1}+\ln{X_2}+...+\ln{X_n}$. However, I don't know how to estimate the p.d.f of $Y$ and calculate the integral. Can anyone gives me some hint?

Comment: If $X_1$ is $U[0,1]$, then $-\log(X_1)$ is $exp(1)$. If moreover $X_i$ are independent, $Y_i = -\log(X_i)$ are i.i.d and $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is $Gamma(n,1)$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: Independence of the $X_i$ would imply that $\operatorname{E}[X_1 X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_n] = 2^{-n}$, so the variable $(X_1 X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_n)^{-n/2} e^{n/2} \to \infty$ a.s. as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I think it is not likely to be correct saying $(0)(\infty) \to \infty$, and it surely has a close form solution.

Comment: $$(2^{-n})^{-n/2} e^{n/2} = 2^{n^2/2} e^{n/2}.$$  Why am I the only one who is seeing this?

Comment: The above condition is equivalent to
$$
{\rm e}b^{-2/n} < X_{1}X_{2}\ldots X_{n} < {\rm e}a^{-2/n}
$$
When $n \to \infty$ it becomes
$$
{\rm e} < X_{1}X_{2}\ldots X_{n} < {\rm e}
$$
but
$$
0 < X_{1}X_{2}\ldots X_{n} < 1
$$
So, it's a kind of contradiction or the result is zero. There is something I don't understand in your question.

Comment: It would be more interesting (and this might be the actual question) to compute $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(a≤(X_1X_2...X_n)^{1/2}e^{n/2}≤b).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following snarski's hint, we have that $Y_i=-\log(X_i)$ has an exponential distribution with unit mean, hence:
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[\log a \leq \frac{n}{2}\sum Y_i +\frac{n}{2}\leq \log b\right] $$
converges to zero since $\sum Y_i$ is concentrated around its mean value, $n$.
Chebyshev's inequality is enough for proving it.

Something significant is the geometric mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, given by
$$ Z = \left(X_1\cdot X_2\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$
By the Central Limit Theorem,
$$ \mathbb{P}[a\leq Z \leq b] = \mathbb{P}\left[\log a \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum(-Y_i) \leq \log b\right]$$
converges to the probability that a $\mathcal{N}(-1,1)$ random variable belongs to $[\log a,\log b]$.

Comment: Can you explain more why it is $N(-1,1)$?

Comment: If $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ is a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the arithmetic mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k $$ converges in distribution to a normal variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. In our case, $-Y_i$ has mean $-1$ and unit variance.

Comment: Thank you! I know how prove its mean=-1 and variance=1 now.

Comment: Sorry but $P(a\leqslant Z_n\leqslant b)$ does not converge to what you say but to $0$ if $a\gt0$ or $b\lt0$, and to $1$ if $a\lt0\lt b$, all by the law of large numbers (not the CLT).

Comment: *Replace each $\gt0$ by $\gt1/e$ and each $\lt0$ by $\lt1/e$.

Answer (score 0):

I invite anyone who uses *Mathematica* to type in the following:

```
F[n_] := (Times @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, n])^(-n/2) Exp[n/2]
Mean[Table[F[1000],{10^5}]]
```

This gives the sample mean of $10^5$ simulations for $n = 1000$.  It is a *huge* number.  Now try `F[10000]`, `F[10^6]`, etc.  The number of digits of these is enormous.  Tell me how this is at all consistent with the other answers posted here, because I have repeatedly suggested there is an error in how the question is posed.

Comment: Yes, $(X_1X_2...X_n)^{-n/2}e^{n/2}$ is typically huge (so much so that there is most probably an error sign in the question, but since the OP does not care...) hence the required probability goes to $0$. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: The contradiction is that your statement that the required probability is zero is not the same as the accepted answer's probability.

Comment: Yes it is (only the first paragraph is answering the question).